# Ajax response is output twice. Console.log only outputs once

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I enqueued the script through WordPress and checked the source, the JS file is only included once.  Using Firebug, I see that the Post is only sent once.  Using Console.log(response), it shows only the single result.

It's outputting my results twice in the HTML though!  What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#cpnsrch').bind('keyup',function(){
    var srch_data = $('#cpnsrch').val();
    if(srch_data.length > 2){
        $.post(bctcdb.ajaxurl,
            {
                'action' : 'search-coupon',
                'data' : srch_data
            }, function(resp){
                if( resp != $('#list-coupons tbody').html() ){
                    $('#list-coupons tbody').html(resp);
                }
                return true;
            }, 'text');  
    }
});
```

I'm at a loss and can't think of any other causes.

[Here's the site if that helps any](http://www.bestcoupontracker.com/cms/coupons/).

Thanks!

-Daniel

edit: Oops, sorry for those that went to the link.  I had it set so only logged in users could see the page.  It should work for anybody now.

Comment: BTW, you can't return a value from an AJAX call, if you are trying to do something with `return true;`

Comment: Oops, yeah, that was a remnant of some of my crazier attempts at keeping it from cycling through twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `<tbody>` closing tag - you have another opening instead of `</tbody>`